# Sqoop failing when importing as avro in AWS EMR

Tags: sqoop, avro, amazon-emr

I'm trying to perform an `sqoop import` in Amazon EMR(hadoop 2.8.5 sqoop 1.4.7). The import goes pretty well when no avro option(`--as-avrodatafile`) is specified. But once it's set, the job is failing with

```
19/10/29 21:31:35 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1572305702067_0017_m_000000_1, Status : FAILED
Error: org.apache.avro.reflect.ReflectData.addLogicalTypeConversion(Lorg/apache/avro/Conversion;)V
```

Using this option `-D mapreduce.job.user.classpath.first=true` doesn't work.

Running locally(in my machine) I found that copying the `avro-1.8.1.jar` in sqoop to hadoop lib folder works, but in the EMR cluster I have only access to the master node, so doing the above doesn't work because it isn't the master node who runs the jobs.

Did anyone face this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was to connect to every node in the cluster(I thought I only had access to the master node, but I was wrong, in EMR we have access to all nodes) and replace the Avro jar that is included with Hadoop by the Avro jar that comes in Sqoop. It's not an elegant solution but it works.

[UPDATE]

Happened that the option `-D mapreduce.job.user.classpath.first=true` wasn't working because I was using `s3a` as target dir when Amazon says that we should use `s3`. As soon as I started using `s3` Sqoop could perform the import correctly. So, no need of replacing any file in the nodes. Using `s3a` could lead to some strange errors under EMR due to Amazon own configuration, don't use it. Even in terms of performance `s3` is better than `s3a` in EMR as the implementation for `s3` is Amazon's.